# .NET 4.0 substitutes for .NET 4.5 namespaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

There is some code for an MVC application which was built using .NET 4.5 as a framework in VS 2012. My current system forces me to work on VS 2010. I managed to open the VS2012 solution in my VS2010, but the thing is that VS2010 supports only up to .NET 4.

There are a few functions in the code which use dll files which are available only for .NET 4.5, for example `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema`.

So, are there any substitute functions/attributes which are available in .NET 4, which I could use to do the same that is being done on .NET 4.5 right now?

This is my current code using .NET 4.5:

```
 [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see `DatabaseGeneratedAttribute` is available under the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` namespace, which is a part of .NET 4.5.

Any suggestions on what the corresponding functions/attributes that could be used in .NET 4 to represent the same logic?

**Note:** In the code snippet given above, I get errors on `Table` and `DatabaseGeneratedAttribute` as

> The type or namespace name 'Table' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and

> The type or namespace name 'DatabaseGeneratedAttributeAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

respectively. So, I am guessing that I just need to find the corresponding classes in NET 4.0 and things would fall into place. Your help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Those annotations [are part of Entity Framework 5.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.103).aspx). (Maybe earlier versions too, I wouldn't know.) Either way, EF5 should work with .NET 4.0, so just add that to your project.

Comment: But sir, I already have EF 5 referenced in my project. Here is the reference `Assembly EntityFramework -D:\Programming\MVC\PassMe\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll`

Comment: And here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute.aspx, it is shown to be available in .NET 4.5 version. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Does [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/468777/Code-First-with-Entity-Framework-5-using-MVC4-and) help? Author claims to be able to use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` in an MVC4 app using VS2010 SP1.

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan : Thank you for the wonderful article! It looks really promising. I will work on it and let you know. Thank you! :)

Comment: Great - I'll move that as an answer, please post back with your feedback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I saw the same issue after changing from .NET 4.5 to 4.0. According to [this article](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/ef5-where-are-my-dataannotations/) "there is a special version of the Entity Framework assembly" for .NET 4.0 containing `DataAnnotations`, which have otherwise been incorporated into .NET 4.5.

Reinstalling Entity Framework made `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` work again. Reinstall by typing the following in Package Manager Console:

```
Uninstall-Package EntityFramework
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

Answer (score 4):

In [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/468777/Code-First-with-Entity-Framework-5-using-MVC4-and), Author claims to be able to use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` in an MVC4 app using VS2010 SP1.

Let us know if this works out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Henrik's solution also works for the opposite situation.  I had an issue with going from .net 4.0 to .net 4.5.1 to support MVC 5.2.3.  I got the same errors.  Uninstalling and Re-Installing Entity Framework solved the problem in this situation as well:

```
Uninstall-Package EntityFramework
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the opposite situation as well! :)

Answer (score 0):

The Package Manager Console didnt work for me.  I had to go Manage Nuget packages to get this issue resolved for me.  I am using VS.net 2013